# how to convert data before applying unique in search filter select in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have question about the following code:

```
if (idx === 3) {
    dt.column(3, { search: 'applied' })
        .data()
        .unique()
        .sort()
        .each(function (d, j) {
            {
                if (renderFunction == null) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                } else {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + renderFunction(d, 'display', null) + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The issue is each cell value in column 3(column.data) is actually a list of string given by the view model. In this case, it is an array. According to other posts I know unique does not work for arrays. I tried to use tostring to convert the data before calling unique, but it's not working. I can't really figure this out. Could anyone help on that?

Thanks!

Comment: Unique does not work for arrays, but works on arrays of DOM elements. Also it is deprecated. To understand more clearly, do each cell store an array of values, or are the cells `(probably <td>)` elements of the array?

Comment: each cell stores an array..basically each cell in column 3 stores a list of string. The worst case I can think of is I do a manual loop to get the unique values.